# Prestashop module admin panel with custom view

Tags: view, module, customization, admin, prestashop

I need to know how to create a module on Prestashop with a custom view on admin. The documentation is very poor and I don't understand how to call a view with parameters passed by the controller. I'm using Prestashop version 1.6.

I already did these steps:

1. Created XML.
2. Created controller with constructor and install/uninstall.
3. Created table on DB and class.
4. Linked on admin menu my module.

When I go to my tab on admin panel I see a table with my db data. I need to load a custom tpl file where I can customize completely my page.

I have read so many guides and documentation (ufficial or not) but nothing clear.

Comment: It depends on what you create exactly. Do you want to: create a module configuration page; create a special admin page to manage some type of custome records; modify existing admin page; override some admin page completely. Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the HTML and CSS in getCOntent() function in your main php file.
 Whatever HTML and CSS return getContent() function will be view of your module in admin panel.

Just concentrate in getContent function of other existing module and you will get what you want.

I f you want to load a separate view than create it separate and load it in getContent() function.